# LinearLayout layout_gravity=right|end does not right align item

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout

I have a very simple layout that isn't working properly and I am stumped!

The ImageView should be aligned to the right of the layout.  Here it is -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_poster_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Tame Impala"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_poster_location_area"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Downtown Toronto"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_poster_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_location_on_24" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can see that the PIN marker is aligned left.

This is very weird behaviour and I don't know what to do!

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]